# Does every amenable group $G$ admit a two-sided Folner sequence?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, amenability

By two-sided Følner sequence I mean a sequence $(F_N)_N$ of subsets of $G$ which is both a left-Følner and a right-Følner sequence.

Context: I just came up with this question and surprisingly I haven't found an answer. I considered the idea of, given a left-Følner sequence $(F_N)_N$, using the sequence $(F_NF_N^{-1})_N$, but it need not be a two-sided Følner sequence (not even when the group is $\mathbb{Z}$, e.g. see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428884/172802)).

Comment: Isn't this in every standard reference? I found the positive answer on google in seconds.

Comment: Stated on page 3 of: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06365.pdf (along with a standard text reference).

Comment: A group $G$ is amenable iff every nonempty $G$-set is amenable (in the sense of Eymard, which means the Følner condition, or equivalently existence of an invariant mean). If $G$ is amenable, so is $G\times G$, and hence $G$, as a $G\times G$-set (action $(g,h)\cdot k=gkh^{-1}$) is amenable.

Comment: I think basically your $FF^{-1}$ works but you have to keep track of how many times each element is produced, and use the definition through almost invariant prob measures.

Comment: @YCor Nice proof that: If $G$ is amenable, then $G$ is amenable!

Comment: @mathworker21 I imagine it's a joke. Properly stated, if $G$ is an amenable $G$-set, it's an amenable $G\times G$-set. The Følner version is not very transparent, essentially for the reason that the Følner criterion doesn't pass well to quotients (unlike the mean or $\ell^1$-criterion).